# DataContext is null when binding to MVVMLight ViewModelLocator Path in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: mvvm-light, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, viewmodellocator

Since Visual Studio 2015 is in RC status I'm not sure if I've found a bug or I'm doing something wrong with my project.

I've created a Viewmodel Locator with MVVM Light and exposed static properties that return the instance of each viewmodel. The locator is registered as a static resource in the app.xaml.

Usually I'll bind this in the Page Xaml with a line like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding Path=MyViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}"
```

However, while I've never had a problem with this working before trying it in VS2015, it is not working in my new project that I am creating for Windows 10.

When I run the project, DataContext is null in the Page, even though it is clearly assigned in the XAML as I've done with dozens of other projects. I checked and the ViewModelLocator static resource is created, initialized, and its MyViewModel property also contains the ViewModel I want. so there's definitely no null references in the VM or the Locator, but for some reason that XAML declaration that binds it to the DataContext of the page appears to be ignored...

I set a break point in the static property getter for MyViewModel in the locator and it is never called...

So I'm not sure if this is a problem with VS2015, MVVM Light, Windows 10 SDK, or Windows 10 itself (current build 10162)...

has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: so the exact same code / project, if loaded on an older VS and target works as it should ?

Comment: good question, I forgot that you can build win 10 on previous versions, i'll try it and update the question, thanks

Comment: sounds like a good starting point :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. the properties to get the individual viewmodels in the locator should NOT be static, and in fact looking at my other projects they never have been.

Here's what I had:

```
public static MyViewModelType MyViewmodel { get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MyViewModelType>(); } }
```

I'm not sure what I was thinking (drinking) making them static this time around, but removing that keyword from the get in the locator property immediately fixed the problem.